# Unit test for my AngularJS directive fails with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have the following definition object for directive "krnGrid":

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        'options': '=',
        'gridModel': '=',
        'stateModel': '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var options = _getDefaultOptions();
        options = angular.extend(options, scope.options);
        options = optionsFactory.gatherOptions(scope, options, element, attrs);

        var events = options.events;
        delete options['events'];
        angular.forEach(events, function (fn, name) {
            element.bind(name, fn);
        });

        //watch configuration object for modifications 
        scope.$watch('gridModel.config', function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
            if (newvalue !== oldvalue) {
                //initialize grid with new configuration options
                _initGrid(scope, element, newvalue.config, options);

            }
        }, true)

        //watch data object for any data updates
        scope.$watch('gridModel.data', function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
            if (newvalue !== oldvalue) {
                //update grid with new data
                _reloadGrid(scope, element, newvalue.data);
            }
        }, true)

        if (scope.gridModel.config.url && scope.gridModel.config.url != '') {
            //load config data from server - TODO - this needs to be a configuration option - need to load data or not should be decided by user
            //scope.gridModel.config.loadConfiguration();
        }

        if (scope.gridModel.data.url && scope.gridModel.data.url != '') {
            //load config data from server - TODO - this needs to be a configuration option
            //scope.gridModel.data.getData();
        }

        _initGrid(scope, element, scope.gridModel.config.config, options);
        _reloadGrid(scope, element, scope.gridModel.data.data)

        var gridObj = element.data().jqxGrid.instance
        scope.stateModel.gridObj = gridObj;

    }
};
```

My unit test is as follows:

```
define("angular-infra/tests/directives/GridDirectiveSpec", ['angular', 'jquery', 'i18n', 'angular-mocks', 'angular-infra/js/directives/Grid'],

function (angular, $) {

    describe("Unit testing grid directive", function () {

        var compile;
        var scope;

        beforeEach(module('html.infrastructure.components'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
            compile = $compile;
            scope = $rootScope;
        }));

        it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function () {
            scope.gridModel = {
                config: {},
                data: {}
            };
            var element = compile('<krn-grid gridModel="gridModel"></krn-grid>')(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            // Following assertion is intentional. Test never reaches this point
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });

    });
});
```

The above unit test fails with the following error message:

```
Chrome 29.0.1547 (Windows 7) Unit testing grid directive Replaces the element with the appropriate content FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
        at link (C:/Kronos/wfc/applications/navigator/html5/angular-infra/js/directives/Grid.js:266:24)
        at nodeLinkFn (C:/Kronos/wfc/applications/navigator/html5/thirdparty/js/angular/angular.js:4222:13)
        at compositeLinkFn (C:/Kronos/wfc/applications/navigator/html5/thirdparty/js/angular/angular.js:3834:14)
        at C:/Kronos/wfc/applications/navigator/html5/thirdparty/js/angular/angular.js:3746:30
        at null.<anonymous> (C:/Kronos/wfc/applications/navigator/html5/angular-infra/tests/directives/GridDirectiveSpec.js:73:81)
```

I'm not able to figure out the cause of this problem. I'm clearly setting the gridModel object in scope in the test.

Does it have anything to do with the isolate scope of the directive? If so, what changes should I make to fix the test?

Comment: Where is line 266 of Grid.js?

Comment: Thanks for offering help, Pablo. This is line 266:

if (scope.gridModel.config.url && scope.gridModel.config.url != ''){

I managed to get past this issue by changing the compile call to:

var element = compile('<krn-grid grid-model="gridModel" state-model="stateModel"></krn-grid>')(scope);

Note that I changed gridmodel="gridModel" to grid-model="gridModel".